# duplicated sessions codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I just finished a script i made and it was working very well but after i uploaded script file and database i found that sessions get duplicated and once i tried opening my website i got this error
[image]

and this is session table now 
[image]

these are session configs from config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'dw_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 36000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'dw_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 60;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.mbm-eg.com/women';
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

And by the way i got this error while i was uploading my sql db file to phpmyadmin maybe it has something related to the problem

[image]

I already contacted server administrator and they are pretty sure it's from the script and no problem with the server .. please help i spent hours search and got no clue :(

Comment: Sessions aren't getting duplicated. The INSERT statement isn't loading the data, as you can see by the VALUES ('','',''... part. Track down where that insert code is and find out why it's not passing the variables.

Comment: Have a look in the session table here the session_id is a primary key; it doesn't allow any duplicate insertion. When you open your website your scropt try to insert the session value to the database. But This session is already added in previous open. 

You can do two job - 
First:-  when anyone logout form your website make sure that the session is destroyed.
2nd - When anyone open your website If any session is already created try to update query which is don't insert session your table you must update the table with new session value.